# Multi-threading with random thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I try to realize Producer-Consumer pattern with several producers and consumers.

I try to make

```
CompletableFuture future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> producer.run(), producerService)
                    .thenRunAsync(() -> consumer.run(), consumerService);
```

where `producer.run()` do something and return `String` but it is not necessary and `consumer.run()` do something like this

```
while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                message = queue.poll();
                if (message == null || !message.equals(thread)) {
                    queue.offer(message);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    continue;
                }
                doWork(message);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
```

My `Thread` has name equals the number of that like 1 or 2, or 3 if there are 3 Threads in `consumerService`.
`message` is a random number which I get with 
`String.valueOf(1 + new Random().nextInt(2))` for 2 Threads as I suppose.

So, my question is
What should I do instead of `thenRunAsync()` or something else that my consumer can be possible to change Thread to take `message` from the queue?

It needs to producer generates a list of numbers like 1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1 and Consumer with Thread which has name 1 get from the queue messages with number equals 1 but Thread with name 2 get with number equals 2.

I can't do every message and after that do `CompletableFuture.allOf()` because, if I'd have about 1_000_000 tasks, I'd have to wait while it generates and after that, I'd be able to call my `consumers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized it like

```
class Stater {

public static boolean STOP = false;
private Producer producer;
private Consumer consumer;
private ExecutorService producerService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(PRODUCER_NUMBER, taxiFactory);
private ExecutorService consumerService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CONSUMER_NUMBER, clientFactory);

 private void working() {

    for (int i = 0; i < PRODUCER_NUMBER; i++) {
        producerService.execute(() -> producer.get());
        consumerService.execute(() -> consumer.run());
    }

    Starter.STOP = true;
    producerService.shutdown();
    consumerService.shutdown();
 }
}


class Common {

private Queue<Message> emergencyQueue;
private BlockingQueue<Message> blockingQueue;

   public void insertOrder(Message message) {
        if (!blockingQueue.offer(message)) {
            emergencyQueue.add(message);
        }
    }

   public Message getOrder() {

        if (emergencyQueue.isEmpty()) {
            if (!blockingQueue.isEmpty()) {
                return blockingQueue.poll();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return emergencyQueue.poll();
        }
    }

   public boolean shouldStop() {
        return blockingQueue.isEmpty() && emergencyQueue.isEmpty() && Starter.STOP;
    }   
}


class Consumer implements Runnable{

private Common common;

   public void run(){
       common.insertOrder(new Message());
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable{

private Common common;

   public void run(){

          while (!common.shouldStop()) {

              Message message=common.getOrder();

              if (message == null) {
               Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(TIME_TO_WAIT));
            }

          }
    }
}
```

Comment: This probably works here, but it's not a good idea. The same instance of both producer and consumer are scheduled several times, which would cause a problem if they had some sort of internal state.

Comment: Why? If they use common blockinQueue, is it a problem? And what do you mean under `The same instance of both producer and consumer`. For each producer/consumer I have their own service

Comment: Try it with a consumer that adds up the value in an `int` and with `CONSUMER_NUMBER` > 2, then output the result after the queue is finished.

Answer (score 2):

CompletableFuture.run* methods are used to run multiple short-living tasks using a thread pool. Your tasks are not short-living, they are looping over queue and handle multiple values. As a result, they occupy threads from the thread pool, and the size of the thread pool decreases, which may lead to a thread starvation (a kind of dead lock).
So you should not use CompletableFuture.run* methods. Use explicit thread creation instead.

Then, make sure that producer puts messages into queue with queue.put() or queue.offer(), and consumer pulls messages with queue.get() or queue.poll(). In your code, consumer both puts and pulls messages, and producer does not interact with the queue at all.

Comment: Why do you think that `consumer both puts and pulls messages`?  I have in code producer.run() which call `queue.offer()` inside of it. After that I call `consumer.run()` which call inside `queue.poll()`

Comment: I do not see neither  producer.run()  nor consumer.run() in your code. All I see is a while loop which invokes both queue.poll() and queue.offer(). I assumed it belongs to consumer.run().

Comment: Hmm...
Haven't you seen `CompletableFuture future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> producer.run(), producerService)
                    .thenRunAsync(() -> consumer.run(), consumerService);` ? It is from main class

Comment: I see calls to producer.run() and consumer.run(), but I do not see their declarations. Besides, I wrote in my answer that such invocations are wrong